# How can I compile a python 3 program into a standalone executable suitable for naive windows users?

Tags: python, windows, compilation

I've looked through the archives and I don't see any solution suitable for sending to a naive user who is used to simply clicking and going.

Also I see that the compiler has been deprecated and removed from Python 3. Does this mean there are 3d party solutions? Would any of them have tutorials? (I'm a pretty naive user myself.)

I have a long list of imports that would have to be included in the executable.

Comment: "Also I see that the compiler has been deprecated and removed from Python 3." Where do you see that? The compiler is still a critical part of the CPython implementation, and certainly hasn't been removed. You're probably misinterpreting something that isn't relevant here, but it's hard to say without knowing what you're talking about.

Comment: Meanwhile, why the "compiler-construction" tag? Have you looked at the description for that tag? Are you trying to build, debug, or introspect a compiler?

Comment: Finally, what does "I've looked through the archives" mean? You've searched SO? You've read a bunch of python-list posts on gmane? Something different? There are a million things that could mean, and nobody wants to give you an answer you've already seen, but that means people might just not try to answer because they assume you've already seen it.

Comment: The official python documentation for v.2.7 says that the compiler is deprecated and been removed from v.3.

Comment: The v.3 documentation does not have an entry for the compiler. -------- I added the tag labelled 'compilation'. It was not labelled 'compiler-construction'. ---- 'Looking through the archives' means I read the SO suggestions as to possibly relevant prior posts. None of them answered my question, mostly being snarky comments, as I see I've encountered here. For all that effort you might have suggested a solution.

Comment: What does "an entry for the compiler" mean? If you're looking for the [`compiler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html) module deprecated since 2.6, that's "a tool for analyzing Python source code and generating Python bytecode. The compiler contains libraries to generate an abstract syntax tree from Python source code and to generate Python bytecode from the tree." The same functionality exists elsewhere in 3.x, but I don't see how that has anything to do with what you want.

Comment: Also, the question very definitely was tagged compiler-construction until John Zwink changed the tags for you, an hour after my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try py2exe0.9.2.0... For Python 3, since cx freeze works on Python 2 only I guess!!

Get it here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0

Answer (score 0):

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) provides exactly what you want, I guess. Download it and check sample codes in the directory. You'd have to manifest a `setup.py` to include third party packages, and infer a specific main program. Many inferences can be searched through Google.

Comment: It is refreshing to have someone attempt to actually answer the question, instead of trying to find fault with its form. This is precisely what I needed to know.

Comment: do py2exe compatible with py3?